# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS Firebase crashlytics detect NSAttributedString formatting crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image][image][image]Firebase crashlytics detect a crash but I am unable to detect it. But after more than 100+ reloading my home page I have generated the crash. Is there has any time related issue?

From LatestFootballNewsAndVideosViewController I call getHtmlAttributedStringLight function and I am trying to assign the returning value into a UILable(self.type3.attributedText=attributedString;). But my LatestFootballNewsAndVideosViewController removefromsuperview 3 or more times. Here I gauge there, has any problem?

LatestFootballNewsAndVideosViewController.m

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    @try {
        NSAttributedString *attributedString=[GlobalVariable  getHtmlAttributedStringLight:description fontName:@"Oswald-Regular" fontSize:20 textAlign:@"left" colorStr:@"#555555"];
        self.type3.attributedText=attributedString;
    }@catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"NSAttributedString converting error");
    }
});
```

GlobalVariable.m

```
+(NSAttributedString*)getHtmlAttributedStringLight:(NSString*)value     fontName:(NSString*)fontName fontSize:(int)fontSize textAlign:    (NSString*)textAlign colorStr:(NSString*)colorStr {
    @try {
        if(value!=nil && ![value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
            return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"<span style=\"font-family: %@; font-size: %dpx; text- align: %@; color: %@;\">%@</span>",fontName, fontSize, textAlign, colorStr, value] dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
        }else{
            return [[NSAttributedString alloc] init];
        }
    }@catch (NSException * e) {
        return [[NSAttributedString alloc] init];
    }
}
```

I used it but same result again.

```
-(void)loadAll { 
    __weak LatestFootballNewsAndVideosViewController  *weakSelf =     self; weakSelf.type3.attributedText=attributedString; 
}
```

Comment: does your font exist?

Comment: yes, font already exist. Here it's name: Oswald-Regular.ttf.  And I used it from here as style="font-family: Oswald-Regular;"

Comment: crash is random or regular? and why do you call try in try?

Comment: Crash are random and I have failed to generate  this crash. First I observe it from firebase. At first there has no try block in my code. But for resolving this issue I have tried it with try and after that try and try. But every time I have failed.

Comment: @AMIT did you found any solution about this, because I'm facing with the same issue?

Comment: I didn't found any stable solution. But after keeping self(__weak ViewController  *weakSelf = self;) reference the error rate have decreased 99%.